# Shell - Read binary file character by character as hex

Tags: shell-script, binary

I'm trying to read serial input(/dev/tty*) character by character. I need this to parse the data following the corresponding protocol. My current method is as follows:

```
while read -rs -n 1 c; do
    echo Read a char:
    echo ${c}
done < "${SERIAL_PORT}"
```

This works, except for the fact that the data is binary and some bytes are \x00, which is not allowed as a character in a variable. My aim is to first convert the byte into a hex string(two characters) which I will then store in the variable. This is where I get stuck. What is a good way to do this? I would prefer to stay posix compliant.

Comment: `od` does this.  Note that you're already not POSIX compliant since you're using other options than just `-r` to `read`.

Comment: od can convert it's input to hex, but how to get in in a variable afterwards?

Comment: While it's definitely possible, probably you might want to read serial input via proper libraries instead of via shell script.  I'd suggest `pyserial` via Python script. Or at a very least `screen` application. Those tools are designed exactly for the job. Shell scripts - not so  suitable for low level stuff like that

Comment: How fast is the serial data coming? You could do an infinite loop of `c=$(dd bs=1 count=1 < ... | od ... | awk ...)` but it might take so long that some data would be missed..

Answer (score 1):

Using `od` to create hexadecimal ASCII representation for each byte/character of input, and outputting these one at a time:

```
od -v -An -txC <input |
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print $i }'
```

This will output one hexadecimal number per line.

You may then read this with `read` if you wish, but it would be better if you could do your processing inside of the already existing `awk` code.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue, but I think od buffers until 16 bytes? Because if I remove the awk it displays as 16 bytes batches

Comment: For this system I need the characters as soon as they're available

Comment: @AartStuurman Then you need to use a language that can read the raw bytes from the input stream.